# What's more natural or idiomatic regard to the combination of feel+miss or longing?

Tags: idiomatic-language

What's more natural or idiomatic regard to the combination of feel+miss or longing?

> I feel I miss her a lot.
>
> I feel I'm missing her a lot now.
>
> I feel longing to her now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "feel" is already contained in "miss", so it should be dropped from the first two examples. In the third example, "longing" acts as a noun, so it can be the object of "feel".

So, these are natural expressions:

`I miss her a lot.`
`I'm missing her a lot now.`
`I feel longing for her now.`

While the third example is possible, it's more natural as
`I long for her now.`

(Note that "longing" takes "for", not "to".)